# FIND_IN_SET() in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-db

I have been troubled in working with the FIND_IN_SET() sql query with zend framework
I have the code like this

```
$profileIds  = "1,2,3";
$matchjobQry = $this->_db->select()->from('user_resume_skill')
                                   ->where('rsl_status=1')
                                   ->FIND_IN_SET('rsl_prf_id ',"$profileIds");
$matchjobRes = $this->_db->fetchAll($matchjobQry);
```

ping me with proper query,,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At last i come to know the exact way of achieving this query,,guys use it**

```
$profileIds  = "1,2,3";
$matchjobQry = $this->_db->select()->from('user_resume_skill')
                                   ->where('rsl_status=1')
//this is the exact way of approaching  zend, and finally got the answer
                                   ->where('FIND_IN_SET(rsl_prf_id,(?))', "$profileIds");
$matchjobRes = $this->_db->fetchAll($matchjobQry);
```